# Calculated textbox does not calculate if Unit Price is formatted as Currency

Tags: vba, ms-access

Simple calculation TotalPrice = QTY * UnitPrice

Does not calculate when I get the Unit Price to display as currency.

The unit price is retrieved from a combo box in the AfterUpdate event as follows:

```vb
Private Sub cboItemRequested_AfterUpdate()
'  0        1        2    3   4           5       6
' ITEM    Category SIZE   UI PRICE   NSN_ORDER   UNIT_PACK

  With Me
    .txtDescrOfItemRequested = .cboItemRequested
    .txtUI = .cboItemRequested.Column(3)
    .txtQTY = 1
    .txtUnitPrice = Format(.cboItemRequested.Column(4), "Currency")
    .txtPartNumNSN = .cboItemRequested.Column(5)    
  End With
End Sub
```

Even though the combo box displays the currency correctly in the 4th column, it does not populate the Unit Price txtbox correctly unless I apply the Format(XXXXX, "Currency"). Incidentally, the textbox is also formatted as currency. However, when I do get the dollar sign to appear, the final calculation TotalPrice remains zero.

I even applied the following to the txtTotalPrice

```vb
=Val(Nz([txtQTY],0))*Val(Nz([txtUnitPrice],0))
```

I tried responding to  @krish KM so I scrapped everything above and instead created this function:

```vb
Public Function cTotalPrice(vQTY As Variant, vUnitPrice As Variant) As Currency

    'only return a value if both fields are numeric

    If IsNumeric(vQTY) = True And IsNumeric(vUnitPrice) = True Then
        cTotalPrice = vQTY * vUnitPrice

    End If

End Function
```

which I only call like this the AfterUpdate event of the cboItemRequested box and any time txtQTY or txtUnitPrice are updated

```vb
.txtTotalPrice = cTotalPrice(.txtQTY, .txtUnitPrice)
```

But txtUnitPrice simply does not display as currency even with txtUnitPrice formatted as currency.

Comment: Call the final calculation within the `afterUpdate` event

Comment: Format function returns text, not number, value. Use textbox properties to format, not VBA. Val(Nz([txtUnitPrce],0)) doesn't work because after formatting with function, txtUnitPrice is a string with a $ character at the beginning. Val() stops when it encounters a non-numeric character, therefore returns 0.

Comment: please see my revised steps above per your recommendation

Comment: You fail on implicit conversion. If you multiply to numbers your format gets lost by that (try`?Format(100,"Currency") * 10`in immediate window). You have to format the result`.txtTotalPrice = Format(cTotalPrice(.txtQTY, .txtUnitPrice), "Currency")`.

Comment: But the result is not the problem.  Not txtTotal Price.   Only the Unit Price.  The result turns out just fine with the dollar sign and all.  That's why this is perplexing.  its the Unit Price who's box I have formatted as Currency and I'm only pasting the exact type of format into the text box.  That value comes from Column(4) of my combo box. Why does it remove the dollar sign?

Comment: @ComputerVersteher, the tip helped me achieve the answer.  I just applied the format to the value as it is being pasted.  But it is a combination of both answers.  I needed to scrap all of the other formatting and apply the final calculation within the afterUpdate event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION:
I needed to Format the txtUnitPrice with VBA

```
.txtUnitPrice = Format(.cboItemRequested.Column(4), "Currency")
```

Yes, the txtBoxPrice formatted as currency just ignores it for some reason.

But in order for the TotalPrice to come out right, it was necessary to recalulate it at the end. This was the first tip I was given.  Thanks krish KM

Comment: Found the initial problem. US currency sign is in front of value and you used the`Val()`function. But the Val function stops reading the string at the first character it can't recognize as part of a number. Test`?Val("$23")`and`?Val("23$")`in immediate window.